# Angular2 ngrx/store, update input data while user is typing

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, rxjs, ngrx

I'm having an issue with the nrgx store in combination with polling and input fields.

Background: we store an object with several child objects in our state. The child objects are used to display their current state but are also used to change some of their values from our frontend.
To display the current state, we need to fetch those objects every 100ms and overwrite our state.

```
state: {
    parent: {
        child: {
            inputProperty: string,
            displaystateProperty: string,
            inputProperty2: string,
            displaystateProperty2: string,
            inputProperty3: string,
            displaystateProperty3: string,
        },
        child2: {
        ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Problem: As we overwrite our state with each polling interval, the user cannot type in an input field as the binding overwrites the input value everytime a new value gets polled.
Ignoring the new value of the input property is also not an option as we need to know if the server accepted the new value.

One solution I have in mind is to split our class into two, one for properties which need to be polled and one for not-polled properties.

Another solution could be to ignore the new values till the user finished typing (lost focus).

I am thankful for any ideas!

Comment: You should change your title to ' Update input data while user is typing ..' . Isn't that your actual problem, not store .

Comment: Actual value is `abcd` , user starting typing `abcdef` then there is an update `abcdpqr` , what do you expect to do. Its just that , there is nothing complicated in code here.